# How to conditionally compare a list and a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime, if-statement

I'm trying to compare a **list** of datetimes for the last 12 hours (from timenow) :

`print(times)`

```
[datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 11, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 8, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 7, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 6, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 5, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 4, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 3, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 2, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 30, 0, 0)]
```

against a number of slices of pandas main dataframe (`filt`):

`print(filt)`

```
             timestamp  switchID    deviceID  count
0  2019-04-29 10:00:00         1  GTEC122277      3
(...)
16 2019-04-30 09:00:00         1  GTEC122277      1
17 2019-04-30 10:00:00         1  GTEC122277      1
18 2019-04-30 10:00:00         1  GTEC122585      1
19 2019-04-30 10:00:00         2  GTEC122585      1
```

Typical Slice:

`print(d1_sw1)`

```
             timestamp  switchID    deviceID  count
16 2019-04-30 09:00:00         1  GTEC122277      1
17 2019-04-30 10:00:00         1  GTEC122277      1
```

I want to check the array `times` against the first column of my SLICED pandas df `d1_sw1`, if they match, then store in a new df in the format:

```
             timestamp  count
0  2019-04-30 12:00:00      0
1  2019-04-30 11:00:00      0
2  2019-04-30 10:00:00      1
3  2019-04-30 09:00:00      1
4  2019-04-30 08:00:00      0
5  2019-04-30 07:00:00      0
6  2019-04-30 06:00:00      0
7  2019-04-30 05:00:00      0
8  2019-04-30 04:00:00      0
9  2019-04-30 03:00:00      0
10 2019-04-30 02:00:00      0
11 2019-04-30 01:00:00      0
12 2019-04-30 00:00:00      0
```

I am really struggling to work out how to achieve this, any help is valued!

I have tried:

```
for times in data['time']:
    if plot_d1_sw1.timestamp.isin(data['time']).astype(datetime):
```

but seem to be getting nowhere with this...